# Calculating the standard deviation from numbers in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviation from a bunch of numbers in a document.
Here's what I got so far:

```
with open("\\Users\\xxx\\python_courses\\1DV501\\assign3\\file_10000integers_B.txt", "r") as f:
total2 = 0
number_of_ints2 = 0
deviation = 0.0
variance = 0.0
for line in f:
    for num in line.split(':'):
        total2 += int(num)
        number_of_ints2 += 1
average = total2/number_of_ints2
for line in f:
    for num in line.split(":"):
        devation += [(int(num) - average) **2
```

But I'm completely stuck. I dont know how to do it. Math is not my strong suite so this this is turning out to be quite difficult.
Also the document is mixed with negative and positive numbers if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why can't you use the built-in [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module's functions for this? Is this a homework problem that restricts you from using external libraries?

Comment: What is the problem with your code (apart from the wrong indentation after 'with')? It seems ok to  me so far. You should divide the deviation with number of ints  - 1 to get the variance, and take the square root to get the standard deviation

Comment: @Stefan Its not indented like that in the program, it happened when it formatted on the website :)

Comment: ... and if you for some reason use Python 2, your division probably is integer division.

Comment: Is there a particular programming problem or do you just not know how to do the math?

Comment: You can [edit] the question and fix the indentation of the code. Please do so if you know that it’s not as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a few available libraries, for example if I had data I got from somewhere

```
>>> import random
>>> data = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)]  # assume from your txt file
```

I could use `statistics.stdev`

```
>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.stdev(data)
28.453646514989956
```

or `numpy.std`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.std(data)
28.311020822287563
```

or `scipy.stats.tstd`

```
>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.stats.tstd(data)
28.453646514989956
```

or if you want to roll your own

```
def stddev(data):
    mean = sum(data) / len(data)
    return math.sqrt((1/len(data)) * sum((i-mean)**2 for i in data))

>>> stddev(data)
28.311020822287563
```

Note that the slight difference in computed value will depend on if you want "sample" standard deviation or "population" standard deviation, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

Answer (score 1):

you may use the function, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) is the official documentation :

Set your numbers in a list, then apply your function :

```
from statistics import stdev
mylist = [1,2,5,10,100]
std = stdev(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are iterating over the file twice, and you didn't reset the reader to the beginning of the file before the second loop. You can use `f.seek(0)` to do this.

```
total2 = 0
number_of_ints2 = 0
deviation = 0.0
variance = 0.0

with open("numbers.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for num in line.split(':'):
            total2 += int(num)
            number_of_ints2 += 1
    average = total2 / number_of_ints2
    f.seek(0)  # Move back to the beginning of the file.
    for line in f:
        for num in line.split(":"):
            deviation += (int(num) - average) ** 2
```